# How can I avoid applicationContext.getBean in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have a class **Bar** implemented as follows:

```
class Bar implements ApplicationContextAware {

    ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    void barFoo() {
        final Foo foo = applicationContext.getBean(Foo.class);
        foo.doSomeWork();
        foo.shutDownProperly();
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }
}
```

And **foo** is defined in my configuration as follows:

```
<bean id="foo" class="biz.tugay.Foo" scope="prototype"/>
```

Since, a Singleton Foo will not do the job properly and it must be shutDownProperly every time..

I think the `getBean` is breaking the whole "dependency injection" / "testable" principle.

But how do I "**inject**" a "**prototype Foo**" into "**Bar**" for the "**barFoo**" method?

Comment: depends on the context, but you might want to use a prototype bean instead of a singleton

Comment: @NickVanderhoven Foo is already prototype, but Bar itself singleton is fine..

Answer (score 3):

So you need to inject a prototype bean in a singleton one, and use a new version of the prototype bean on each call of a method of the singleton.

You could try to use a ScopedProxyFactoryBean, but the Spring Framework Reference Manual advise the lookup method injection.

You `Bar` class will become:

```
class Bar implements ApplicationContextAware {

    ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    void barFoo() {
        final Foo foo = createFoo();
        foo.doSomeWork();
        foo.shutDownProperly();
    }

    protected abstract Foo createFoo(); // Implementation will be provided by Spring Framework
}
```

You simply have to declare the method in the bean definition:

```
<bean id="foo" class="biz.tugay.Foo" scope="prototype"/>
<bean id="bar" class="biz.tugay.Bar">
    <lookup-method name="createFoo" bean="command"/>
</bean>
```

References (emphasis mine):

> Singleton beans with prototype-bean dependencies
> ..
>   However, suppose you want the singleton-scoped bean to acquire a new instance of the prototype-scoped
>   bean repeatedly at runtime. You cannot dependency-inject a prototype-scoped bean into your
>   singleton bean, because that injection occurs only once, when the Spring container is instantiating the
>   singleton bean and resolving and injecting its dependencies. **If you need a new instance of a prototype
>   bean at runtime more than once, see the section called “Method injection”**.

and

> Lookup method injection
>
> Lookup method injection is the ability of the container to override methods on container managed beans,
>   to return the lookup result for another named bean in the container. The lookup typically involves a
>   prototype bean [...]. The Spring Framework implements
>   this method injection by using bytecode generation from the CGLIB library to generate dynamically a
>   subclass that overrides the method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use org.springframework.beans.factory.ObjectFactory:

```
class Bar {

@Autowired
private ObjectFactory<Foo> fooObjectFactory;

}
```

then you can get Foo object by:

```
 Foo foo = fooObjectFactory.getObject();
```

Comment: All implementations of ObjectFactory seem to be private inner classes and Autowired does not seem to work.